# DMA IRQ Not Firing STM32L010F4

Tags: stm32, uart, dma

Started a project based on the STM32L010F4 which needs to receive six bytes from the UART. Works fine if I use it in interrupt mode. Does NOT work if I use it in DMA mode. Saw multiple posts about the DMA needing to be init'd before the peripheral in question. Made sure this is the case. Still nothing: IRQ does not fire, callback is not called. What am I missing?

```
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
uint8_t RX_Data[6] = {6};
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  uint8_t Result = HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, RX_Data, 6);

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      //uint8_t Result = HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, RX_Data, 6);
      //uint8_t Result = HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, RX_Data, 6);

      if( Result == HAL_OK )
      {
          HAL_Delay(20);
      }
  }
}


void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback (UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    HAL_Delay(20);
}




* @brief USART2 Initialization Function
   * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{
    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 57600;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    } 
}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn);

}

/**
 * @brief UART MSP Initialization
 * This function configures the hardware resources used in this 
 example
 * @param huart: UART handle pointer
 * @retval None
 */
void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(huart->Instance==USART2)
  {
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**USART2 GPIO Configuration
    PA0-CK_IN     ------> USART2_RX
    PA2     ------> USART2_TX
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* USART2 DMA Init */
    /* USART2_RX Init */
    hdma_usart2_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel3;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(huart,hdmarx,hdma_usart2_rx);

    /* USART2_TX Init */
    hdma_usart2_tx.Instance = DMA1_Channel2;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_usart2_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
       Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(huart,hdmatx,hdma_usart2_tx);

    /* USART2 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
  }

 }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how the DMA gets configured? This will be in something like `HAL_UART_MspInit()` in `stm32f0xx_hal_msp.c`.

Comment: "Does NOT work if I use it in DMA mode." What exactly do you expect to happen? Do you expect a certain function to be called? And is it a STM32L010F4 or a STM32F010F4 MCU? Text and title differ.

Comment: @Codo Corrected title. I am expecting either the callback function (HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback) to be entered, or the IRQ handler (DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQHandler) to be called. Neither happen.

Comment: Does the data appear in the buffer? i.e. is the problem that you don't receive the data, or you don't get an interrupt?

Comment: Also somewhat confused by your DMA channels. You have this: `HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn);` but also this: `hdma_usart2_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel3; hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;`Seems like a possible mismatch.

Comment: The codes looks correct to me. The channel and request numbers are the ones generated by STM32CubeIDE and match the reference manual. Are you sending at least 6 characters? Before that, the callback function will not be called. Are you sure you have the correct baud rate?

Comment: @Codo, yes, the baud rate is correct, and I am sending six bytes.

Comment: @pmacfarlane - I get one byte of data in the buffer. So the IRQ doesn't fire, because it's expecting six bytes. But I'm not sure why I am only gettng the one byte. FWIW, I know what value the first byte should be, and it is correct. If I change it to HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, RX_Data, 1); the IRQ fires and the callback is called.

Comment: Turns out the STM32L010F has a bug where when using USART2 , DMA channel 3 can ONLY receive one byte. It's in the Errata for the part. Seems like Cube shouldn't use that channel if this is known.